# Flutter firebase logged in user returns a NULL currentUser after sign in

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

When authenticating in firebase using the signInWithEmailAndPassword() API, I am unable to get a valid "current" user.

1. I sign into the application with user name and password

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword()
```

2. I once signed in the user is taken to a Home page
3. I attempt to get the user's UID but there is no valid user returned. The call happens in an async function as such:

```
currentUser = await auth.currentUser();
```

currentUser is null.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you reload the returned FirebaseUser? This worked for me.

```
const User currentUser = await auth.currentUser;
if (currentUser != null) {
  await currentUser.reload();
}
```

Clearly simplified code. Note: auth.currentUser() is now auth.currentUser.

This might be a duplicate: [Flutter Firebase Authentication currentUser() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50439051/flutter-firebase-authentication-currentuser-returns-null/65221367#65221367).

Comment: This answer isn't applicable here. The question states that the first call to auth.currentUser returns null. Therefore, the code suggested in this solution--calling currentUser.reload()--will never be executed.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation suggests that you use an [auth state observer](http://It%20might%20work%20when%20testing%20locally) to get a callback when the user is signed in and a User object is available.  As shown in that linked documentation:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
```

I strongly suggest **not** relying on `currentUser`, as that can only check at a moment in time.  The observer is guaranteed to let you know when the user object is available for use.

Answer (score 0):

after getting user just reload it once it will solve your problem
code for reference :D

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User currentuser;
  bool isloggedin= false;
  getUser() async{

    User user =  _auth.currentUser;
    await user?.reload();
    user =  _auth.currentUser;

    if(user !=null)
    {
      setState(() {
        this.currentuser = user;
        this.isloggedin=true;
      });
    }
  }
```